# Find the pdf of the random variable x given by?

Tags: statistics

$f(x)= \frac{c}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $0<x<4$

```
   0 for elsewhere
```

Find $P(X<\frac{1}{4})$ and $P(X>1)$ and find the value of c.

This is what I did.

For $P(X<1/4)$

$\int_0^{1/4} x^{\frac{-1}{2}}dx + \int_\infty^0 0$

and I got $c 2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}$

for $P(X>1)$ I did

$\int_1^4 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\int_4^\infty 0$

and I got

$c(2\sqrt{4}-2\sqrt{2})$

But how would I find c. I am not sure

Comment: There are some formating issues here, and it's not immediately clear that $f$ is the pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of a probability density over its support must equal $1$, so this means $c$ must satisfy $$\int_{x=0}^4 \frac{c}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx = 1.$$

Comment: In this case I guess C=1/4

Comment: @FernandoMartinez That is correct.  Now that you know $c$, it is a simple exercise to compute the probabilities $\Pr[X < 1/4]$ and $\Pr[X > 1]$.

Comment: I see so my chosen integrals are correct I think.